# how to test datetime select input on cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I need to write a cucumber test to test datetime select behavior.

here is my sentence:
When I select "2012-4-30 15:00" as the "start_time"

here is my html view:

```
      = form_tag time_off_requests_path do
      = label :time_off_request, :start_time, 'Start Time'
      = datetime_select :time_off_request, :start_time , :start_year => Time.current.year, :use_short_month => true

      = submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```

I tried something like
When /^I select "([^"]*)" as the "([^"]*)"$/ do |date_time, label|
  select(date_time, from => label)
end
but it doesn't work. get can not find id, name for "select box"
really need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime_select` helper generates a **set** of select, not a single form field. You should write a custom step to assign each part of your datetime (day, month, year, hour...) to the corresponding field.

Answer (score 0):

This is the custom step for cucumber tests I have created for inputing to fields generated from a datetime_select:

```
When /^(?:|I )select datetime "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - ([^:]*):([^"]*)" as the "([^"]*)"$/ do |year, month, day, hour, minute, field|
  select(year,   :from => "#{field}_1i")
  select(month,  :from => "#{field}_2i")
  select(day,    :from => "#{field}_3i")
  select(hour,   :from => "#{field}_4i")
  select(minute, :from => "#{field}_5i")
end
```

In your test, you call it like:

```
When I select datetime "2014 March 2 - 19:00" as the "start_time"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use select_date cucumber helper

```
select_date '2014-01-01', from: 'Start Time'
```

example step:

```
When(/^I choose "([^"]*)" in "([^"]*)" date select$/) do |value, select_label|
  select_date value, from: select_label
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber-rails/Cucumber/Rails/Capybara/SelectDatesAndTimes